# Longest line segment in a convex polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in direction $\mathbf{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra

Let us consider a non-empty convex polyhedron $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and a vector $\mathbf{n} \in \mathbb{R}^3$. If we choose a point $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, then $ \mathbf{x}$ and $ \mathbf{n} $ define a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let us denote the line by $\mathbf{p}_{\mathbf{x}}$.

I would like to pick such a point $\mathbf{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that the interception of $\mathcal{C}$ and line $\mathbf{p}_{\mathbf{x}}$ is maximal. Let us denote the endpoints of a line segment given by the intersection of $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathbf{p}_{\mathbf{x}}$ by $\mathbf{a}_{\mathbf{x}}$ and $\mathbf{b}_{\mathbf{x}}$. Hence, I want to solve the following optimization problem

$$ \underset{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3}{\text{argmax}} \| \mathbf{b}_{\mathbf{x}} - \mathbf{a}_{\mathbf{x}} \| .$$

I think that it would be impractical to formulate a general optimization problem and try to solve it numerically. I assume that we can use the convexity of $\mathcal{C}$ and only consider the lines that that follow direction $\mathbf{n}$ and pass through the vertices of $\mathcal{C}$. However, I don't know how to properly argument this and I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: project the edges to a plane perpendicular to $n$. Let $C$ be the collection of intersection of the edges' images. Among those line segments parallel to $n$ with maximal length, at least one of them intersect with the plane at a point in $C$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @achillehui. I can visualize your method, but I don't see why it would work. Could you elaborate more about the theory no which it is based?

Comment: treat the length of line segments as a function of the point of intersection. For those point where the length is non-zero, it is the minimum of a bunch of linear function. For a point not lie on images of edges. the length cannot be a local minimum unless it is locally constant. In that case, there are points on nearby edge-images with same length. If that point on the edge isn't lie on intersection of other edges, then the length (restricted along the edges) cannot be a local maximum unless it is locally constant. In that case again, there are points on intersection with same length.

Comment: [This](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2020.10.021) paper might be useful

Comment: Why is it impractical to write the problem as linear program?

Comment: Mainly due to the problem arising from coming up with an explicit formula for $\mathbf{a}_{\mathbf{x}}$ and $\mathbf{b}_{\mathbf{x}}$.

Comment: You don't need an explicit formula for them. Let me write an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $\mathcal C$ has non empty interior it is enough to look for $\mathbf x$ inside $\mathcal C$ which is equivalent to solving the following linear program:

$$\max\, t :\, \mathbf y - \mathbf x = t\mathbf n,\, \mathbf x\in \mathcal C,\, \mathbf y\in \mathcal C$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The idea is brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> I assume that we can use the convexity of $\mathcal{C}$ and only consider the lines that that follow direction $\mathbf{n}$ and pass through the vertices of $\mathcal{C}$.

Unfortunately, this isn't true. Consider the gyrobifastigium:

[image]

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a shape roughly like this, with coordinates of $(\pm 1, \pm 1, 0)$, $(0,\pm 1, 1)$, and $(\pm 1, 0, -1)$. Take $\mathbf{n}$ to be the vector $(0,0,1)$, so we're trying to find the point above which $\mathcal{C}$ is "tallest".

Clearly, the maximum possible height is $2$, since $\mathcal{C}$ is bounded below by $z=-1$ and above by $z=1$. But this height is only attained at the segment from $(0,0,-1)$ to $(0,0,1)$, along which $\mathcal{C}$ has no vertices.

I believe we *can* assume that $\mathbf{x}$'s location on a plane $\mathbf{n}^\perp$ orthogonal to $\mathbf{n}$ is *either* a vertex of $C$ or the intersection of the projections of two edges of $C$ onto $\mathbf{n}^\perp$, so we can still restrict our attention to a finite set, but it might be substantially larger. (There are likely ways to prune this set to a more manageable size, though.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to generalize the argument in two dimensions, but now I see why my idea is flawed. If I understand your argument correctly, then your method is the same as @achillehui in the comments.